# SQL AVG gives the same average for all Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, average

I'm trying to get an average mark of each assessment, currently I'm getting the same average for each assessment. [this is the entity relationship of my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhbE77.png).

**I use this statement:**

```
SELECT cid, name, AVG(mark) FROM Assessment, Grade GROUP BY name, cid ORDER BY cid, name;`
```

**My Result is :**
 [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZ837J.png)

Comment: I'm selecting my mark from 'Grade' as my statement says 'From Assessment, Grade'. Im new to sql so this might be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is an (old style) cross join of the tables which returns all the possible combinations of the 2 tables.
Instead join properly the tables with a condition in the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT a.cid, a.name, AVG(g.mark) 
FROM Assessment a INNER JOIN Grade g
ON g.aid = a.aid
GROUP BY a.cid, a.name 
ORDER BY a.cid, a.name
```

Answer (score 1):

If i got your question, you are trying to get the avg marks per assessment(aid).
For that you would first join the tables Assessment and Grade.

Then group by the fields (aid,cid,name) --> Just aid would be sufficent, since its the primary key, however if you need to get the other values then you would need to group those fields as well.

```
select a.aid
      ,a.cid
      ,a.name
      ,avg(g.marks) avg_marks_by_assessment
  from assessment a
  join grade g
    on a.aid=g.aid
group by a.aid
        ,a.cid
        ,a.name
```